# how can I make my Image fade back in androidstudio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-animation

I'm very new to programming & so far I could not find a specific answer for my problem , so very short here is my problem :

I'm working with android studio 2.2.3

when I click on the first image it changes to second image

```
public void fade(View view) {

        ImageView ja1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ja1);

        ImageView ja2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ja2);

        ja1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);

        ja2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);


    }
```

now when I want to make the second image which is already visible to fade and first images comes back by using fade nothing happens ! and my app won't even do anything ! I'm just stuck on first image here is the code I try to use :

```
public void fade(View view) {

        ImageView ja1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ja1);

        ImageView ja2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ja2);

        ja1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);


        ja2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);


        ja2.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);


        ja1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);

    }
```

I would be really grateful if someone can help me out ,

thank you kindly.

update : here is my xml codes ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.dlx.myapplication.MainActivity"
    android:onClick="fade2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ja1"
        android:id="@+id/ja1"
        android:onClick="fade" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ja2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/ja2"
        android:alpha="0" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It will not work. You know why?? Because the first image only fade to alpha 0 but it still remains at the top of the other. So you are not able click the 2nd image. Try using if statement. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

you should make the reverse action in a new method:

```
public void fadeImageView1(View view) {

    ImageView ja1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ja1);

    ImageView ja2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ja2);

    ja2.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);

    ja1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
}
```

call this method when clicking on ImageView2 after ImageView1 faded away.

Comment: Thanks , I already have tried that in a new method Public void as you mentioned but the second method will not work , app is only able to execute whatever is in the first public void , fade image 1 and bring image 2 but not the reverse !

Answer (score 0):

This way works for me I have a method to make one disappear and the other appear and vice versa. Code...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView ja1,ja2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   ja1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ja1);
    ja2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ja2);

    ja1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fadeIN(getCurrentFocus());
        }
    });

    ja2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fadeOUT(getCurrentFocus());
        }
    });

}

public void fadeOUT(View view) {
            ja1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
            ja2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
            ja2.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
            ja1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
        }

public void fadeIN(View view) {
    ja2.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
    ja1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
    ja1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
    ja2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
}

}
```

Comment: thanks , well this is very strange , I tried the codes you posted here the first image fades away and second comes in but vice versa will not happen ! the exact problem I'm having from the start

Comment: Make sure you have ja1 and ja2 swapped for the animations in the methods

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that an alpha of 0 does not make an image unclickable. You could try having a transparent button over top of both of them and just switch on a boolean when that is clicked,or make the alpha 0 image visibility.GONE, or some variation of that.

Comment: well my second image which is ja2 starts with alpha of 0 , my first ja1 starts with 1 then when I click on the screen which includes first image it goes away alpha of ja1 changes to 0 and ja2 comes up with alpha of 1 , my problem is I can not make the vice versa action , when I click on the second image to bring back the first one nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

```
public void fade(View view) {

    ImageView cat1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cat1);

    ImageView cat2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cat2);

    float alpha = cat2.getAlpha();

    if (alpha == 0) {

        cat2.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(3000);

        alpha = 1;
    }

    else {

        cat2.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(3000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, I initialized an integer i to 1 and then based on its value I ran the different codes:

```
package com.example.dell.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;  
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public int i = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void bbd(View view) {



    Log.d(" value of i is ", String.valueOf(i));
    if (i == 1) {
        i++;
        ImageView img2 = (ImageView) findViewById((R.id.cc));
        img2.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bb);
        img.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);

    } else if (i == 2) {
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bb);
        ImageView img2 = (ImageView) findViewById((R.id.cc));
        img.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
        img2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
        i--;

    }
   }

   }
```